# Xamarin.iOS : Facing The file “” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it. 257 issue on real iOS device

Tags: iphone, permissions, xamarin.ios

We are using "UIDocumentPickerViewController" to select the files from iOS device storage.

After that when we are trying to get the data from the file URL as below, it returns an error message.  This issue I am facing only on the real iOS devices and on the iOS simulator, it working fine.

```
try
{
    var picker = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(allowedUTIs, UIDocumentPickerMode.Open);
    picker.WasCancelled += Picker_WasCancelled; 
    picker.DidPickDocumentAtUrls += (object s, UIDocumentPickedAtUrlsEventArgs e) =>
    {
        var fileUrl = e.Urls[0].AbsoluteString; // given below
        NSUrl videoNSUrl = NSUrl.FromString(fileUrl); 
        videoNSUrl.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource(); 
        // videoData = NSData.FromUrl(videoNSUrl);         
        NSDataReadingOptions nSDataReadingOptions = new NSDataReadingOptions();
        NSData videoData = NSData.FromUrl(videoNSUrl, nSDataReadingOptions, out NSError error); 
        Console.WriteLine(error.ToString()); // error message given below                              
        videoNSUrl.StopAccessingSecurityScopedResource();                         
    };
    PresentViewController(picker, true, null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Crashes.TrackError(ex);
}
```

Error message:

```
The file “file_example_PPT_250kB.ppt” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
257
Domain "NSCocoaErrorDomain"
File path:  file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/01DEB59C-EFF4-4E8A-A7CC-4CD3177FC8CA/File%20Provider%20Storage/Downloads/file_example_PPT_250kB.ppt
```

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are they running under the same iOS version? And try to modify the `UIDocumentPickerMode` to `import`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @KyleWang-MSFT UIDocumentPickerMode to import fixed the issue.